# Hadoop replication Issue during hive inserts

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I've been getting this error over and over when running a test that is inserting a bunch of records into a table using hive.  The nature of the error makes it appear to not be related to my code but rather some system issue.  I just can't figure out what that might be. The code I'm running is doing about 100 or so individual inserts into a table via hive jdbc.

```
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10293]: Unable to create temp file for insert values File /tmp/hive/hive/4a7308b4-34e5-4fee-91c8-3e8e946ebfd5/_tmp_space.db/Values__Tmp__Table__242/data_file could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 4 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1641)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getNewBlockTargets(FSNamesystem.java:3198)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3122)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:843)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:500)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:640)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2313)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2309)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2307)
```

Comment: The error message said it can't create a temp file.  Did you look at HDFS to see if you have exhausted the filesystem?

Comment: I might also try checking the NameNode logs. For some reason, NameNode thinks there's nowhere to place the new file blocks.

Comment: The HDFS was only at 22% utilization so that doesn't appear to be the issue.